# Manometer Reading from Fluid Dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics

so I have been working on this problem :

1. Diameter1 at wide end: 8cm   ||  V1 = 1.56m/s
2. Diameter2 at narrow end: 3cm   ||  V2 = 11.094m/s

***Find the manometer reading***

[image]

I know that due to Bernoulli's Equation the pressure where velocity is at 11.094m/s is much lower than at the other end. This can also be seen from the Mercury(Hg) level.

**I have take P2 as being 0 because it is open to the atmosphere  -- I am unsure whether this should be taken as 0 or 1.**

I have used the following equation to work out P1 :

```
P1+(1/2 ρv1^2)=P2+(1/2 ρv2^2) and I end up with P1 = 60.321kPa
```

Can I use : 1 − 2 = (2 −1)ℎ in order to find the height ? Or is thus equation only valid for a differential manometer that has a constant cross sectional area ?

I am still unsure how to proceed in this case. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT** This question is not related to finding any sort of velocity as asked in the possible related question. I am interested in the manometer reading and if the equation  1 − 2 = (2 −1)ℎ  is relevant in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fluid Dynamics pressure and velocity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305046/fluid-dynamics-pressure-and-velocity)

Comment: Big no-no: Why are you reposting the exact same question you have asked before?

Comment: The context is taken from the same question however this is a completely different Problem. I have not yet solved it. I used some relevant information from the link you gave me from the other question but that was only to find the velocity and not the manometer readings.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the absolute value of the pressure is; all you need is the difference, $p_1-p_2$. Your number is wrong. $\frac{1}{2}\rho(v_2^2-v_1^2)$ should come to around 0.6 atmospheres. Your manometer equation will be $\rho_{Hg} h=p_1-p_2$.

Comment: On the plus side, your velocities are correct ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Pirx for your insight once again. I solved the velocities according to what I read in that good pdf you suggested.  I had a stupid mistake in my calculations for P1. It must be getting late :)

Comment: @Pirx, however in your calculation you are not taking into consideration the density of water. The formula I was using takes both the density of water AND Hg into consideration.

Comment: Hmm, yes, looking at your figure again, you're right.

Comment: @Pirx, you stated that my velocities are correct. Did you actually check these ? Because I am getting an h value of 4.8 m and I am doubting that this is too large, thus meaning that my velocities were calculated badly.

Comment: $4.8\,\mbox{m}$ is too large, but not because of the pressure difference, which is correct. Plug in the correct numbers and you should get something much more reasonable. Hint: Watch your decimal point ;-)

Comment: ...and don't forget $g$.

Comment: @Pirx, I was not dividing by `g`  at the end. Now my answer is equal to 0.479 m . Much more reasonable, however still pretty big I would think for the other figures given. There is a big probability that the values given to me were not thought trough well enough.

Comment: On what basis do you make the assessment that "the values given to [you] were not thought through well enough"? Which one of these values do you think are unrealistic, and why?

Comment: The question I am reading is from my friends example paper done over a year ago. All the values that were given (diameter of each end and F) were altered differently for each paper that was handed out. Therefore the answer to the height could have varied by quite a substantial amount from question to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem like this, you first calculate the velocity in the two sections - the ratio of the velocities is the inverse of the ratio of the areas for an incompressible fluid.

The manometer will read a pressure that depends on the difference in density between mercury and water, so

$$\Delta p = \Delta \rho g h$$

The absolute pressure doesn't matter here, just the difference. So you can rewrite this as

$$\frac12 \rho_w (v_2^2 - v_1^2) = (\rho_m - \rho_w) g h$$

You asked:

> Can I use : 1 − 2 = (2 −1)ℎ in order to find the height ?

The short answer is "yes", assuming you are careful with your signs. $P_1<P_2$, but $\rho_1 < \rho_2$ so in your expression you would get a negative $h$ but the way you drew it, the value looks positive. But that's easy enough to get right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciated. The answer is coming to around 0.48 m. Pretty big for the other dimensions however I think that this is the correct answer.